# NodeJS Socket.IO Single Connection on Cluster

Tags: node.js, socket.io, cluster-computing

I have a small lottery like game where users can enter in different rooms and server emits some random numbers to the rooms. Everything works well with single instance of the app but when I try to implement any clustering option,  my app starts to behave differently like the number emits from server not shown or number is shown 2-3 times. I have added socket.io-redis, sticky-session and redis but its not helping. Tried clustering option with PM2, Node cluster module and nginx ip_hash load balancer but no help. Can someone please help on configuring setup so that I can run multiple instance of my app on single machine so that I can take advantage of machine's resources.

Basically I want my Socket.IO to create only one connection across all the instances.

Thanks

Comment: is your frontend connected to all the servers at the same time?

Comment: It looks like all the instances are creating socket connection and serve as a different app.

Comment: You may want to look into [load balancers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_balancing_(computing)) to make sure that every connection is unique (for example using a Round Robin strategy)